# Is it possible to overload macros that contain VA_ARGS for logs?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, variadic-templates, variadic-macros

I try overload WriteLogs macro with 1 and 2 params:

```
template <typename... Args>
void WriteLog(const LogContext& logContext, const LogSettings& logSettings, std::string formatMsg, Args... args) {
    // ...
    printf("formatMsg", args...);
    // ...
}

#define WriteLog_1(message, ...) WriteLog(LogContext{__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__}, LogSettings{false, 0}, message, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define WriteLog_2(settings, message, ...) WriteLog(LogContext{__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__}, settings, message, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define GET_MACRO(_1, _2, NAME, ...) NAME
#define WriteLogs(...) EXPAND(GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, WriteDebug2, WriteDebug1)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

so is it possible to overload them for usage:

```
int main() {
   WriteLogs("hello %s, %d + %d = %d", "world", 2, 2, 5); // WriteLog_1
   WriteLogs(LogSettings{true, 0}, "hello %s, %d + %d = %d", "world", 2, 2, 5); // WriteLog_2
}
```

Comment: Rather than attempting an overload with the preprocessor, just write two `WriteLog` functions.

Comment: I need use preprocessor to avoid writing explicilty "LogContext{__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__}"

Comment: What I'm saying is, keep the macro but without any complex logic, somethinig like `#define WriteLogs(...) WriteLog(LogContext{...}, __VA_ARGS__)`. Then make two `WriteLog` functions to make it work with and without the extra argument.